# C# datagridview get current cell value before Drag&Drop value

Tags: c#, datagridview, drag-and-drop

I have a dgv and a richtextbox. the user can select a name from the rtb and drag to a cell in the dgv. i have this working fine if there is no value in the current cell they drop into. however, if the cell has a value and they drop a value over that cell i lose the previous value. Here is my DragDrop code

```
if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(typeof(System.String)))
        {
            Point clientPoint = gridViewRaces.PointToClient(new Point(e.X, e.Y));
            gridViewRaces.Rows[gridViewRaces.HitTest(clientPoint.X,
            clientPoint.Y).RowIndex].Cells[gridViewRaces.HitTest(clientPoint.X,
            clientPoint.Y).ColumnIndex].Value =
            (System.String)e.Data.GetData(typeof(System.String));
        }
```

before the value is inserted in the cell i would like to be able to retrieve the current value if present like so..

```
string currentValue = gridViewRaces.Rows[e.Y].Cells[e.X].Value.ToString();
```

any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: Why cant you do exactly that before you proceed to drop the new data?

Comment: @ŇɏssaPøngjǣrdenlarp i am getting a System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException

Comment: @ŇɏssaPøngjǣrdenlarp I worked out a solution myself. thanks for taking the time to lok at it though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After Hours of pulling my hair out i finally realised i had the answer the entire F*****G time.

This was the code that inserts the values being dragged -

```
if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(typeof(System.String)))
    {
        Point clientPoint = gridViewRaces.PointToClient(new Point(e.X, e.Y));
        gridViewRaces.Rows[gridViewRaces.HitTest(clientPoint.X,
        clientPoint.Y).RowIndex].Cells[gridViewRaces.HitTest(clientPoint.X,
        clientPoint.Y).ColumnIndex].Value =
        (System.String)e.Data.GetData(typeof(System.String));
    }
```

and to get the previous value before new value is inserted all i had to do was this

```
string previousValue = gridViewRaces.Rows[gridViewRaces.HitTest(clientPoint.X,
            clientPoint.Y).RowIndex].Cells[gridViewRaces.HitTest(clientPoint.X,
            clientPoint.Y).ColumnIndex].Value.ToString();

            gridViewRaces.Rows[gridViewRaces.HitTest(clientPoint.X,
            clientPoint.Y).RowIndex].Cells[gridViewRaces.HitTest(clientPoint.X,
            clientPoint.Y).ColumnIndex].Value =
            (System.String)e.Data.GetData(typeof(System.String));
```

hope this helps someone sometime.